# Merge ram and memory tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

Both tags [ram](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ram) (x7) and [memory](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memory) (x69) deal with the same thing (or rather the questions tagged thus do). Strictly spoken, RAM is part of memory -- but in daily use, they are used synonymously. So I'd suggest we do the same, and merge the 7 questions "ram" into "memory", plus making "ram" a synonym to "memory".

Comment: All 69 questions with `memory` talk about RAM and not internal storage?  Seems unlikely, I've seen them confused more often than not (sadly).  If anything I'd merge the reverse direction for clarity.

Comment: Matthew is right, memory is often used for "internal storage", so the synonym target should be ram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this the other way around (making [memory](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memory) a synonym of [ram](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ram)) because I agree with Matthew's comment:

> All 69 questions with memory talk about RAM and not internal storage? Seems unlikely, I've seen them confused more often than not (sadly). If anything I'd merge the reverse direction for clarity.

[memory](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memory) is simply not a great tag. It invites people to misuse it, and before performing the merge I ended up retagging ~20 questions that were using [memory](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memory) to refer to their internal storage (which we specifically have [internal-storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internal-storage) for). Therefore, I think that making [ram](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ram) the master tag is the better idea.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference between RAM and memory (in or out the questions)

> RAM is sometimes called "memory" for short which further complicates
>   the issue. RAM is a computer chip that assists in speed of the
>   computer that is measured in Megabytes (MB) or Gigabyte (GB) depending
>   on the size of the chip. When a user chooses to open a file, the
>   computer must put that information somewhere to be able to access it.
>   It writes the file temporarily to the RAM for easy access. RAM also
>   temporarily saves files that are currently being worked on.

So I agree with you that they should be merged.